# Kotlin coruntines wont execute when in a launch and callback

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I thought I was familiar enough with Kotlin's coroutines, until I got this code.

1 to 8 are all printed except 2:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.lang.Runnable
import java.lang.Thread.sleep
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        Client.createAccount()
        delay(1000)
    }
}

object Client: CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = newSingleThreadContext("Client")

    fun createAccount() = launch {
        Client2.init(Runnable {
            println('1')
            launch {
                println('2')
            }
            ok()
            ok2()
        })

        println('7')
        launch {
            println('8')
        }
    }

    fun ok() {
        println('3')
        launch {
            println('4')
        }
    }

    fun ok2() = launch {
        println('5')
        launch {
            println('6')
        }
    }
}

object Client2 {

    fun init(runnable: Runnable) = thread {
        sleep(100)
        runnable.run()
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
7
8
1
3
4
5
6
```

The coroutine in callback will never be called. Why?
And if I remove the `launch` in `createAccount()` the 1 to 8 will be all printed.
Also if I use `GlobalScope.launch { println('2') }` instead of `launch { println('2') }`, I can also get the 2 printed.

Answer (score 3):

the reason is that anonymous class uses its wrapper scope as a parent.

`launch { println('2') }` in `Runnable { }` will be cancelled when parent job `createAccount()` launched is completed.

Therefore, it can't be invoked because it would be cancelled right after `launch { println('8') }`.

So, If you change `Client` like below, it would print '2' correctly.

```
object Client: CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main

    fun createAccount() = launch {
        Client2.init(Run())

        println("7")
        launch {
            println("8")
        }
    }

    fun ok() {
        println("3")
        launch {
            println("4")
        }
    }

    fun ok2() = launch {
        println("5")
        launch {
            println("6")
        }
    }

    class Run: Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            println("1")
            launch {
                println("2")
            }
            ok()
            ok2()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really solved my question! And can you give me some guide or document to know about the behavior of wrapper scope? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure... but it would be that anonymous inner class has its wrapper dependency originally in jvm, not by coroutine. if I was wrong, please let me know.
(+ I figured out your problem by converting to kotlin bytecode)

Answer (score 0):

launch posts a Runnable in a Handler, so its code execution is not immediate.
launch(Dispatchers.Main, CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED) will immediately execute its lambda expression in the current thread.

change the dispatcher to the current one you are using 
change the lunch from inside the thread to

```
launch (coroutineContext, CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED)
```

.

```
fun createAccount() = launch {

    Client2.init(Runnable {
        println('1')
        launch (coroutineContext, CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED){
            println('2')
        }
        ok()
        ok2()
    })

    println('7')
    launch {
        println('8')
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
7
8
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: thanks for giving me this solution, it works well! And also I found CoroutineStart.ATOMIC works toobut I don't understand why 4 and 6 was printed, while 2 won't be printed. Choim answer my doubts, maybe you can check it out